# JQuery .find() failing on an .ajax() result

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a Chrome extension which, under certain conditions, performs a `$.ajax()` request and then uses information of specific elements in the returned `HTML`. For now, I'm simply trying to have it access the specific element and log it to the console to ensure it works correctly.

To start, I am fairly certain the `HTML` is successfully retrieved. When I log the result directly, the output is identical to the result when I view the page source in Chrome. I've also tried using `$.parseHTML()` which, when logged, gives me an array of top-level children. Using selectors returns an array of the immediate children matching the selector, but they do not work for elements which are children of these children (and so on).

I've looked at several posts already, and tried a variety of things such as using `$(<selector>,<context>)`, `$(<result>).filter(<selector>)`, and `$(<result>).find(<selector>)` to no avail. Every time I try to log these I end up with an object of length `0`.

```
$.ajax({jsonp: false, dataType: "html",url: getUWFlowLink($(this).attr('href')), success: function(siteHTML){

    console.log($("p.description",siteHTML));
    console.log($("p.description",$.parseHTML(siteHTML)));
    console.log($(siteHTML).find("p.description"));
    console.log($($.parseHTML(siteHTML)).find("p.description"));
    console.log($(siteHTML).filter("p.description"));
    console.log($($.parseHTML(siteHTML)).filter("p.description"));

}});
```

All of these logs simply return objects with `0` length. Trying to log the `.html()` results in an output of `undefined`, and trying to log the `.text()` results in an empty string for output. A sample page, for reference is [here](https://uwflow.com/course/che102). The element I am trying to access is the description blurb at the top ("Chemical principles with applications...") and its location in the HTML (a few levels deep) can be found by inspecting the element.

Comment: Might you have a cross-origin problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure -  this is my first time working with JQuery let alone chrome dev and ajax. But as far as I'm aware, with chrome extensions cross-origin is possible when the site is put in the permissions of the manifest and you specify `jsonp:"false"`. The HTML appears to be retrieved successfully though I am not 100% on it.

Comment: If you are loading your HTML file from a different domain than the ajax call is going to, and you don't have a special set-up on the server, you will get cross-origin problems.  The data will go to the browser, but the browser won't let javascript have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var $result = $('<div />').append(siteHTML);
$result.find('p.description');
```

jQuery requires a tree structure to traverse and perform its operations. Directly trying to use `.find()` without having a root element would not work. In the above case `$('<div/>')` would be the root element and by appending the result, jquery would be above to traverse it and find `p.description`.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have resolved my issues with `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a "View page source" for the sample page you linked, you'll find that the element you are looking for looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="course-inner-tpl">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6 left-col">
    <p class="description"><%- course.get('description') %></p>
...
```

This means that the element is being rendered on the browser dynamically after loading. It won't be part of the DOM tree when jQuery parses it, as it is inside a `<script>` tag.

Note that you can also find the course description on the same page in a static `<meta>` tag that you should be able to access.

EDIT: If you need additional information, you can parse the relevant script to get it. The following code will iterate over all the scripts in the page, find the one that contains the info, extract the text defining the `coursOjb` object, and parse it as JSON:

```
$('<div />').append(siteHTML).find('script').each(function(s) {
   var t = $(this).text();
   var p = t.indexOf('window.pageData.courseObj = {');
   if( p > 0 ) {
       var e = t.indexOf(';', p);
       var d = JSON.parse(t.substring(p+28, e));
       console.log(d.code);
       console.log(d.name);
       console.log(d.description);
       console.log(d.prereqs);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It works now when I use the version in the `<meta>` tags. Is there a way for me to obtain the dynamically-rendered data? Some of the other elements on the page I need do not appear to have static elements elsewhere.

Comment: There is no easy way. One approach would be trying to load the page inside an iframe and wait for it to render the element. Another would be trying to parse or evaluate the `<script>` element containing the data (the one starting with `window.pageData.courseObj = ...`.

Comment: With my limited knowledge of `HTML`, l would be inclined to try the second method for the sake of efficiency/overhead... How would I go about using that section for information? It looks like `JSON` to me but I honestly have no clue how I'd go through it with `JQuery`.

Comment: I think in my confusion with all these new concepts I completely forgot about simple strategies like string manipulation! This works perfectly - you are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully getting the HTML and not running into Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues, I have tested the below to work in test cases:

```
var description = $(siteHTML).find("p.description").html();
console.log(description);
```

If you can console.log(siteHTML) and it is giving you output, then you should be able to query the response with jQuery, however there may be some limitations to which query selectors work when not adding the HTML to the DOM.